# PHP errors after upgrading to Playa 4.4.4

Tags: playa

I'm getting the following error a number of times on the Edit Entry page in the Control Panel after upgrading to Playa 4.4.4 on EE 2.5.5:

```
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice
Message: Array to string conversion
Filename: playa/helper.php
Line Number: 179
```

The front end seems to be ok.

PHP version is 5.2.17.

Comment: Same here with Playa after update to 4.4.4, on EE 2.6.1.

Comment: Same issue here, but only on certain channels. Playa 4.4.4 & EE 2.6.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed in 4.4.5, but passing along from P&T Support for 4.4.4:

Replace offending line in third_party/playa/helper.php with:

```
if (!is_array($category) && (strlen($category) > 4 && (strtolower(substr($category, 0, 4)) == 'not ') || (strtolower(substr($category, 0, 4)) == 'not_')))
```